# If the same val is used to replace two separate string.Format placeholders, must it be provided twice?

Tags: c#, string.format

Given this:

```
string msg = string.Format("Duckbill {0} Platypus has not been loaded. Fetch Duckbill {1}'s Platypus then continue.", userDuckbill, userDuckbill);
```

...would it suffice to do this instead:

```
string msg = string.Format("Duckbill {0} Platypus has not been loaded. Fetch Duckbill {1}'s Platypus then continue.", userDuckbill);
```

?

Comment: A moment of testing would have saved you a couple of moments on stackoverflow. It really would be easier to test than to ask in this case.

Comment: Not in my case; it takes several minutes to test the simplest thing.

Comment: I recommend http://www.linqpad.net

Comment: I've got Linqpad, but I'd either forgotten or didn't know that it worked with non-LINQ stuff.

Comment: With this in LINQPad:

MessageBox.Show("This is {0}", "this");

...and "C# Statement[s]" selected, when I mash the Green Arrow [!TM], I get, "The name 'MessageBox' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: You've got a good point, though - I tried to give myself a thumb's down, but it won't let me do that. The reason for my failed attempt at self-flagellation: I should have fired up VS2010 to test it out, even though with the project I'm working on I've got to use VS1903 (well, VS2003, but it's effectually the same thing).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can specify a parameter any number of times. Use this instead:

```
string msg = string.Format("Duckbill {0} Platypus has not been loaded. Fetch Duckbill {0}'s Platypus then continue.", userDuckbill);
```

The [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) has several examples like this. Here's just one:

```
  string formatString = "    {0,10} ({0,8:X8})\n" + 
                        "And {1,10} ({1,8:X8})\n" + 
                        "  = {2,10} ({2,8:X8})";
  int value1 = 16932;
  int value2 = 15421;
  string result = String.Format(formatString, value1, value2, value1 & value2);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `{0}` twice:

```
string msg = string.Format(
    "Duckbill {0} Platypus has not been loaded. Fetch Duckbill {0}'s Platypus then continue.",
    userDuckbill);
```

Your second code sample would result in a `FormatException` with the following message:

> Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than
>   the size of the argument list.

So, whenever you use `{n}`, you must have at least `n` parameters after your format string. Having more than `n` would be useless however.